# nth-child increase decrease with click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of li elements forming a menu. When the user clicks a particular li element I want to change the source of an iframe element to the URL that corresponds to the clicked item.

I've tried the function below but it didn't work. Can somebody please advise how to do this?

**http://jsfiddle.net/ZnMTK/8/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var source1="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr";
    var source2="http://www.milliyet.com.tr";
    var source3="http://www.vatan.com.tr";
    var source4="http://www.ensonhaber.com";
    $("#menubar ul li:nth-child(i)").click(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', source(i) );
    });
});
```

Comment: I've reworded your question to reflect what you're actually trying to do. Your original wording seemed to be asking something quite different, and the real intent was only clear in the fiddle - please don't rely on external links (such as your fiddle) to explain what you are asking. (It's definitely helpful to provide a fiddle to illustrate the problem, but don't rely on that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array and then use the clicked `li` elements index to fetch the target source from array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sources =["http://www.hurriyet.com.tr","http://www.milliyet.com.tr","http://www.vatan.com.tr","http://www.ensonhaber.com"],
    $("#menubar li").click(function(){
       $('#iframe1').attr('src', sources[$(this).index()])
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mxNcH/)

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality is what arrays are for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sources =["http://www.hurriyet.com.tr","http://www.milliyet.com.tr","http://www.vatan.com.tr","http://www.ensonhaber.com"],
    i = 0;
    $("#menubar li").click(function(){
        $("#iframe1").attr('src', sources[$(this).index()] );
    });
});
```

However, specifying all of your URLs in your JavaScript and relying on the indices matching up with the order of the menu li elements is kind of fragile. I would recommend linking the values more closely, perhaps something like this:

```
<ul id="menubar">
    <li data-src="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr">Hurriyet</li>
    <li data-src="http://www.milliyet.com.tr">Milliyet</li>
    <li data-src="http://www.vatan.com.tr">Vatan</li>
    <li data-src="http://www.ensonhaber.com">Ensonhaber</li>
</ul>
```

And then with JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menubar li").click(function () {
        $("#iframe1").attr('src', $(this).attr("data-src"));
    });
});
```